# Buy signal on one Timeframe and sell signal from another, tradingview

Tags: pine-script

my breakout trend following model uses weekly candles to initiate an initial buy or sell short signal but my stop loss (only when below my entry price) is based on 2day candles.  Is there anyway to write a script to generate my stop losses on the weekly chart that are derived from 2 day candles?

Thanks, Brenden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requesting data from lower timeframes is not supported and not recommended. Please see [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html#requesting-data-of-a-lower-timeframe).

You can use your script on the `"2D"` timeframe and request weekly data from there to figure out your buy and sell conditions. Then use the current timeframe (`"2D"`) to calculate the SL.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much, that's incredibly helpful as I am totally ignorant as far as coding.  Do you happen to know if there a place where one can go to hire someone that specializes in this Pine script of trading view?

Comment: Yes. Tradingview itself provides a list of trusted pine developers. You can find the list [here](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000601677-where-can-i-find-a-reliable-pine-programmer-to-hire/)